# Woocommerce Storefront Theme; Show "available on backorder" on checkout page, on the individual product

Tags: php, woocommerce, storefront

Hello i'm on my first webshop project, and mostly been doing normal wordpress websites in the past. I am making the shop with woocommerce and the storefront theme.

On the website the owner want the customers to be able to see the "available on backorder" message that i linked in the first image to where the red line is on the second image.
The first image is from the shopping cart page, and the second is on the checkout page.

[Picture one of the shopping cart page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzGDz.jpg) and [Picture of the checkout page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0x2U.jpg)

So the problem is i dont really know how to add the code for showing it on the individual product on the checkout page.

Since im still pretty new to the add_filter or function coding, i dont really have anything to show other than the two related pictures I hope the question makes sense, since english isnt my first language.

Comment: We expect you to provide in your question your own real code attempt. Please note that StackOverFlow is not a free coding service.

Comment: Please show your work or attempts to solve the problem and what didn't work for you.